# knitr Rmd to md and the YAML header

Tags: r, knitr

I use knitr to render md from Rmd.  The YAML header `:output` is not changed in that process.  Is that inteded?  After all the output of the md file is not md anymore.

As an example (please excuse the bad formatting -- I do not know how to make that work properly)

```
---
output:
  md_document:
    variant: markdown_github
---

# Test Document

This is a test document.
```

is rendered with `knit(test.Rmd)` into

```
---
output:
  md_document:
    variant: markdown_github
---

# Test Document

This is a test document.
```

Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

knitr doesn't care about the header, you probably mean to use `rmarkdown::render`